Ошибка Исключение - Class "format_base" not found в Moodle
При попытке установить устаревший плагин и отмены установки появилась ошибка "Ошибка
Исключение - Class "format_base" not found". Буду рад любой подсказке решения этой проблемы, кроме восстановления резервной копии сайта и советов про то, что устаревший плагины надо проверять на резервной копии сайта.
